# Right way to use ListView and ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, observablecollection

I'm using ListView with items bind as ObservableCollection. Each object have their get, set, for example:

```
public string NamePar
        {
            get
            {
                if (_namePar == null)
                {
                    if (_productID > 0)
                    {

                        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cString.c_String))
                        {
                            conn.Open();
                            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("...", conn))
                            {
                                using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                                {
                                    while (rdr.Read())
                                    {
                                        _namePar = rdr[0].ToString();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return _namePar;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_namePar == value)
                    return;
                _namePar = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("NamePar");
            }
        }
```

So I have question about it:

- Is it right way to use SqlConnection in each get?
- Should I maybe use one SqlConnection and use it without opening new
  every times?
- Why when I select item in ListView it goes to get everytimes
  (sometimes even 20x to same get?), for example it goes to
  productCount, then to productPrice, then again to count etc? I know
  that, if value != null then it will just return previous (private)
  value, but maybe I'm doing something wrong

Thank you very much for any help! :)

Comment: For Performance, depending on your Environment, you should not open a SQL Connection on every get.

You could use a constructor to read all values from your database at once. After this you could call the same method that updates all your properties if you Need to refresh it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But is there any way not to enter every 'get', even after selectionchanged in listview?

Comment: I haven't done much with observablecollections, but i would guess that wpf checks if the value has changed every time you click or Change the listview. And this is causing the calls on the getters...

Answer (score 3):

Noooooooooooooooooooo!

Don't open `SQLConnections` in your getters!

A better approach would be to only set the `NamePar` property when you need to.

Here's an example of what I mean:

Create a class for your item, like so:

```
public class MyItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

It's the responsibility of whoever **creates** the list of items to populate it's property values. So you need to create a method which will refresh the list. For example:

```
public void Refresh()
{
    //Open a SQL Connection

    //Get the records you need

    //Populate an observable collection of [MyItem] with the records from the database.
}
```

By moving the SQL Connection stuff higher up the food chain, to the View Model, you've already gained some performance as you're no longer running queries in your property getters.